# How to recongnise routes in a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, dashboard, rails-engines

I have this very basic question. I am using this [dashboard rails engine](https://github.com/gottfrois/dashing-rails), and this gives me a `views/layouts/dashing/dashboard.html.erb`. This is the layout of the dashboard view.

But I want to customize this view, like add a navigation bar, that has a link which point to my `about_path`. However, none of the routes are recognized in the dashboard view. It results in an error `undefined method about_path`.

But the `about_path` route is defined in my routes file and is working fine in other views that dont belong to dashboard.

Is there any way a rails engine recognizes routes defined in my application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to reference the application inside the engine in a similar way, use the main_app helper:

```
<%= link_to "About", main_app.about_path %>
```

here is link for reference [rails routes guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#routes)